# Set value to a form variable outside the form context

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm building an "advanced search" form, and the results are show in the same page, and in some place in the page I have to place the pagination controls, with can be the usual 1,2,3...N pages, or prev and next buttons.

So far I tried to add a new field named `page` that will receive a integer representing the current page number but I can't see how I can set value to this field from outside the form, in this scenario I'm placing the pagination control at the bottom of the page.

Another try was by GET parameter, sending the page parameter on the query so I can handle what page to show on the controller, but in the scenario I didn't succeeded to preserve the field values when the page was refreshed.

So, following my past tries, I would need to achieve: set form values from outside the form on the TWIG template OR refresh the page without losing the form values. In any case I'm not sticking to any specific solution and any suggestion is welcome.

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Card;
use App\Entity\CardImage;

use App\Repository\CardRepository;
use App\Repository\CardImageRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

use App\Form\CardSearchForm;

use App\Services\Scryfall\Scryfall;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted;

/**
 * @Route("/admin/card", name="app_admin_card_")
 */
class CardController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;
    /**
     * @var CardRepository
     */
    private $cardDao;
    /**
     * @var CardImageRepository
     */
    private $imageDao;
    /**
     * @var Scryfall
     */
    private $scryfall;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, CardRepository $cardRepository, CardImageRepository $cardImageRepository, Scryfall $scryfall)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->cardDao = $cardRepository;
        $this->imageDao = $cardImageRepository;
        $this->scryfall = $scryfall;
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/search", name="search")
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_WRITER")
     */
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $cards = [];

        $form = $this->createForm(CardSearchForm::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $cards = $this->scryfall->search( $form->getData() );
            
            if ($cards->object == 'list') {
                foreach ($cards as $key => $card) {
                    // $thisCard = $this->saveCardIfNotExists($card);
                    // $cards->data[$key]->local_id = $thisCard->getId();
                }
            }
            // var_dump($cards);die;
        }

        return $this->render("admin/card/search.html.twig",["cardSearchForm"=>$form->createView(), 'cards' => $cards, 'currentPage' => $form->get('page')->getData() ]);
    }

    private function saveCardIfNotExists($card) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class CardSearchForm extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var Security
     */
    private $security;


    /**
     * CardSearchForm constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('q', TextType::class, [
                'empty_data' => 'Nome da carta, tipo, texto do oraculo, etc...',
                'required' => true
            ])
            ->add('include_extras', CheckboxType::class, [
                "attr"=>["class"=>"iCheck-helper"],
                "required" => false,
            ])
            ->add('include_variations', CheckboxType::class, [
                "attr"=>["class"=>"iCheck-helper"],
                "required" => false,
            ])
            ->add('order', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'  => [
                    'Nome (A → Z)' => 'name',
                    'Coleção (AAA/#1 → ZZZ/#999)' => 'set',
                    'Data de lançamento (Mais nova → Mais antiga)' => 'released',
                    'Raridade (Comum → Mítica)' => 'rarity',
                    'Cor (WUBRG → multicolor → colorless)' => 'color',
                    'Valor de mana (0 → Mais alto)' => 'cmc',
                    'Poder (Mais baixo → Mais alto)' => 'power',
                    'Resistência (Mais baixo → Mais alto)' => 'toughness',
                    'Ranking do Commander (EDHREC) (Mais baixo → Mais alto)' => 'edhrec',
                    'Artista (A → Z)' => 'artist',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('dir', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'  => [
                    'Automatica' => 'auto',
                    'Ascendente' => 'asc',
                    'Descendente' => 'desc',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('page', HiddenType::class, [
                'data' => 1
            ]);
    }
}
```

Twig:

```
{% extends "admin/bars.html.twig" %}

{% block contenpage %}
    <div class="">
        <div class="page-title">
            <div class="title_left">
                <h5>
                    <a href="{{ path('app_admin_card_search') }}">
                        {{ "backend.global.search"|trans }}</a>
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                    <div class="x_title">
                        <h2>Monte sua busca nos campos a baixo:</h2>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox"></ul>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="x_content">
                        {{ form_start(cardSearchForm, {'id': 'search_form'}) }}
                        {{ form_row(cardSearchForm.q, {'label': 'Busca'}) }}
                        {{ form_row(cardSearchForm.include_extras, {'label': 'Incluir extras?'}) }}
                        {{ form_row(cardSearchForm.include_variations, {'label': 'Incluir variações?'}) }}
                        {{ form_row(cardSearchForm.order, {'label': 'Ordenar por?'}) }}
                        {{ form_row(cardSearchForm.dir, {'label': 'Organizar em?'}) }}

                        <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                        <div class="item form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                                <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ path('app_admin_card_search') }}">
                                    {{ "backend.form.clear"|trans }}
                                </a>
                                <button type="submit" name="valider" class="btn btn-success">
                                    {{ "backend.form.search"|trans }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        {{ form_widget(cardSearchForm) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        {% if cards is not empty %}

            <div class="">
                <div class="page-title">
                    <div class="title_left">
                        <h5>{{ "backend.global.search_result"|trans }}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="x_panel">
                            {% if cards.object == "error" %}
                                <div class="x_title">Sua busca não retornou nenhum resultado</div>
                            {% else %}
                                <div class="x_title">Mostrando
                                    {{cards.data|length}}
                                    de
                                    {{cards.total_cards}}</div>
                                {% for card in cards.data %}
                                    {# {{dump(card)}} #}
                                    {{ (loop.index % 3 == 1) ? '<div class="row mt-3 h-100">'|raw }}
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                            {% if (card.layout == "transform" or card.layout == "modal_dfc")  %}
                                                <div class="flip-card">
                                                    <div class="flip-card-inner">
                                                        <div class="flip-card-front">
                                                            <img src="{{ ( card.card_faces[0].image_uris is defined ) ? card.card_faces[0].image_uris.normal : '' }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ card.card_faces[0].name }}">
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="flip-card-back">
                                                            <img src="{{ ( card.card_faces[1].image_uris is defined ) ? card.card_faces[1].image_uris.normal : '' }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ card.card_faces[0].name }}">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            {% else %}
                                                <img src="{{ ( card.image_uris is defined ) ? card.image_uris.normal : '' }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <h5 class="card-title">{{ (card.printed_name is defined) ? card.printed_name : card.name }}</h5>
                                                {% if card.card_faces is defined %}
                                                    <p class="card-text">{{ (card.card_faces[0].oracle_text is defined) ? card.card_faces[0].oracle_text : '' }}.</p>
                                                {% else %}
                                                    <p class="card-text">{{ (card.oracle_text is defined) ? card.oracle_text : '' }}.</p>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            </div>
                                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                                {% if card.card_faces is defined %}
                                                    <li class="list-group-item">{{ (card.card_faces[0].mana_cost is defined) ? card.card_faces[0].mana_cost : '' }}</li>
                                                {% else %}
                                                    <li class="list-group-item">{{ (card.mana_cost is defined) ? card.mana_cost : '' }}</li>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                <li class="list-group-item">{{ (card.printed_type_line is defined) ? card.printed_type_line : card.type_line }}</li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Ad. a um deck</a>
                                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Ad. a coleção</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    {{ (loop.index is divisible by(3)) ? '</div>'|raw }}


                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>

                        {% set currentPath = path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'),
                       app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) %}

                        {{dump(currentPath)}}

                        {{ _self.pagination(cards.total_cards, currentPage, currentPath) }}
                    {% endif %}

                </div>
                {% macro pagination(total, current, url, nearbyPagesLimit = 4) %}
                    {% apply spaceless %}
                    {% if total > 1 %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="pagination-area">
                                    {% if current > 1 %}
                                        <a class="prev page-numbers" href="{{ (url ~ '/' ~ (current-1))|e }}">Prev</a>
                                    {% endif %}

                                    {% for i in 1..total %}
                                        {% if 0 == (current - nearbyPagesLimit) - loop.index %}
                                            <a class="page-numbers" href="{{ (url ~ '/' ~ 1)|e }}">1</a>
                                            {% if 1 != loop.index %}
                                                <span class="page-numbers">...</span>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% elseif 0 == (current + nearbyPagesLimit) - loop.index  and (current + nearbyPagesLimit) < total %}
                                            <span class="page-numbers">...</span>
                                        {% elseif 0 < (current - nearbyPagesLimit) - loop.index %}
                                        {% elseif 0 > (current + nearbyPagesLimit) - loop.index %}
                                        {% else %}
                                            {% if current == loop.index  %}
                                                <span class="page-numbers current" aria-current="page">{{ loop.index }}</span>
                                            {% else %}
                                                <a class="page-numbers" href="{{ url ~ '/' ~ loop.index }}">{{ loop.index }}</a>
                                            {% endif %}

                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    {% if current != total  and (current + nearbyPagesLimit) < total %}
                                        <a class="page-numbers" href="{{ (url ~ '/' ~ total)|e }}">{{ total }}</a>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if current < total %}
                                        <a class="next page-numbers" href="{{ (url ~ '/' ~ (current+1))|e }}">Next</a>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endapply %}
                {% endmacro %}
            {% endblock %}
```

Comment: For what you will set the page in the form if you submit a GET Request in the pagination?

Comment: It was just part of the tries, I setted the hidden page field in a attempt to change it value from outside the form, at the botton of the page. Also I tried to pass the page as a GET but i loose the values inputed in the form.

Comment: Yes, you ever must submit all search parameters to do it work. This can be by use a route with all search parameters or a little javascript function that change the hidden page field and submit the form. Another posibility is to store the actual search paraameters to the session.

Comment: I managed to solve based on your suggestion, I stored the search parameters on the session and used javascript to handle the populate the page parameter on the form and submit when the pagination was clicked, thanks.